# HTML numeric character references cause an error in JavaDocs

Tags: html, javadoc

Including `&#12539;` in JavaDocs source causes errors like

`error: invalid entity &#12539;`

(Java 8 on Windows).

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148480) on this. The problem is the check, generation probably works fine.

Try [unicode escape characters](http://jedit-users.narkive.com/wgSpXIMU/jedit-users-character-to-entities-for-javadoc) instead.

Alternative is do disable doclint (which will turn the check off).

Comment: You mean `\uxxxx`?  Unfortunately we found those don't render properly on Safari.

Comment: @Mohan Yes thats what I mean.

Comment: @Mohan Alternative is to disable doclint (which disables the check).